# How to use TypeScript's async/await and fetch with parameters?

Tags: typescript

I've used the following code:

```
let response = await fetch("/LostEnergyCalculation/GetGridAndPieChartsData");
let data = await response.json();
```

without parameters and it works fine, but how to use it with parameters?

Comment: That's not TypeScript. Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: The async/await is in TypeScript and I use it in TypeScript's classes.

Comment: @tesicg do you mean querystring?

Comment: No. I mean on calling MVC action as in my code but with parameters.

Comment: Can you try with `await fetch("/LostEnergyCalculation/GetGridAndPieChartsData"+"/"+param1+"/"+param2)` you have to handle the route in MVC

Comment: The question is clear - how to use fetch with parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to `POST` data in your fetch, you can pass a `body` with the request...

The example below passes form style data in the request, and returns typed data using an interface.

```
interface MyApiData {
    name: string;
}

class Example {
    async getData(foo: string, bar: string) {
        let response = await fetch(
            '/LostEnergyCalculation/GetGridAndPieChartsData',
            {
                method: 'post',
                headers:new Headers({
                    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                }),
                body: `foo=${foo}&bar=${bar}`
            });

        let data: MyApiData = await response.json();
        return data;
    }
}

const example = new Example();

example.getData('foovalue', 'barvalue').then((data) => {
    alert(data.name);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Please, take a look at my answer below.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to make it work in way you presented. It works in another way I've found in the meantime. It's in separated comment bellow.

Answer (score 0):

My method (event handler) looks as following:

```
async onFieldSelectionChanged() {
    const selectedOilField = $("#OilFieldsList").dxSelectBox("instance");
    this.oilFieldId = selectedOilField.option("value");
    if (this.oilFieldId === null) {
        selectedOilField.option("value", 1);
        this.oilFieldId = 1;
    }

    if (this.initialLoad) {
        const startDateBox = $("#StartDate").dxDateBox("instance");
        this.startDate = startDateBox.option("value").toISOString();
        const endDateBox = $("#EndDate").dxDateBox("instance");
        this.endDate = endDateBox.option("value").toISOString();
        const periodGroup = $("#DateTimePeriod").dxRadioGroup("instance");
        this.period = periodGroup.option("value");

        //$.ajax({
        //    type: "POST",
        //    url: "/LossEnergyCalculation/GetGridAndPieChartsData",
        //    data: { oilFieldId: this.oilFieldId, periodGroup: this.period, startDate: this.startDate, endDate: this.endDate }
        //}).done(data => {
        //    this.showDataGrid(data);
        //    this.showRealLossDonutChart(data);
        //    this.showNormativeLossDonutChart(data);
        //    this.initialLoad = false;
        //}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //    console.log("jqXHR: " + jqXHR.responseText);
        //    console.log("jqXHR status: " + jqXHR.status);
        //    console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
        //    console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        //});

        const response = await fetch("/LossEnergyCalculation/GetGridAndPieChartsData",
            {
                method: "post",
                headers: new Headers({
                    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                }),
                body: "oilFieldId=${this.oilFieldId}&periodGroup=${this.period}&startDate=${this.startDate}&endDate=${this.endDate}"
            });
        const data = await response.json();
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

It fails on calling fetch method with an error that you can take a look at the screen shot attached.

[image]

By the way, the commented ajax call works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this way to make it work:

```
let queryString = [
    `oilFieldId=${this.oilFieldId}`,
    `periodGroup=${this.period}`,
    `startDate=${this.startDate}`,
    `endDate=${this.endDate}`
].join('&');

const request = new Request(`/LossEnergyCalculation/GetGridAndPieChartsData?${queryString}`,
    {
        method: "POST"
    });
const data = await fetch(request).then(response => response.json());
```